# Zeep create xs:choice element

Tags: python, xml, wsdl, zeep

I have wsdl with **ArrayOfVEHICLE** type:

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfVEHICLE">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="VEHICLE" nillable="true" type="tns:VEHICLE"/>
            <xs:element name="VEHICLEV2" nillable="true" type="tns:VEHICLEV2"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I am trying to create element with that type with zeep:

```
vehicle_v2_type = client.get_type("ns0:ArrayOfVEHICLE")
vehicle_v2 = vehicle_v2_type(VEHICLEV2={...})
```

And I get an error:

```
TypeError: {http://www.vsk.ru}ArrayOfVEHICLE() got an unexpected keyword argument 'VEHICLE2'. Signature: `({VEHICLE: {http://www.vsk.ru}VEHICLE} | {VEHICLEV2: {http://www.vsk.ru}VEHICLEV2})[]`
```

I have tried using **_value_1** method from [zeep docs](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#nested-using-value-1) like this:

```
vehicle_v2 = vehicle_v2_type(_value_1={"VEHICLEV2": {...}})
```

And I get another error:

```
TypeError: No complete xsd:Sequence found for the xsd:Choice '_value_1'.
The signature is: ({VEHICLE: {http://www.vsk.ru}VEHICLE} | {VEHICLEV2: {http://www.vsk.ru}VEHICLEV2})[]
```

Anybody knows how to create that element with zeep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i got it. My wsdl says that choise element got to be list, because of signature:

```
<xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
```

And the easy way is to create [Nested list using _value_1](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html#nested-list-using-value-1), without factories in my case

```
client.service.SomeService(
    ...
    vehicles={  # Element with ArrayOfVEHICLE type
        "_value_1" : [
            {
                "VEHICLE2": {...}
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Hope this wil help someone